# Is Solr SuggestComponent able to return shingles instead of whole field values?

Tags: solr, autocomplete, autosuggest

I use solr 5.0.0 and want to create an autocomplete functionality generating suggestions from the word-grams (or shingles) of my documents.
The problem is that in return of a suggest-query I only get complete "terms" of the search field which can be extremly long.

**CURRENT PROBLEM:**

Input:"so"
Suggestions:
"......extremly long text **so**n long text continuing......"

"......next long text **so**lar next text continuing......"

**GOAL:**

Input: "so"

Suggestions with shingles:

"**so**n"

"**so**lar"

"**so**lar test"

etc

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent" 
               enable="${solr.suggester.enabled:true}"     >
<lst name="suggester">
  <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>      
  <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
  <str name="field">title_and_description_suggest</str>
  <str name="weightField">price</str>
  <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">autocomplete</str>
  <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">autocomplete</str>
 <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
</lst>
```

schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="autocomplete" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball"/>
      <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I want to return max 3 words as autocomplete term. Is this possible with the SuggestComponent or how would you do it? No matter what I try I always receive the complete field value of matching documents.

Is that expected behaviour or what did I do wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In schema.xml define fieldType as follows:**

```
 <fieldType name="text_autocomplete" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

**In schema.xml define your field as follows:**

```
<field name="example_field" type="text_autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**Write your query as follows:**

```
query?q=*&
rows=0&
facet=true&
facet.field=example_field&
facet.limit=-1&
wt=json&
indent=true&
facet.prefix=so
```

In the facet.prefix field, specify the term being searched for which you want suggestions ('so', in this example). If you need less than 5 words in the suggestion, reduce maxShingleSize in the fieldType definition accordingly. By default, you will get the results in decreasing order of their frequency of occurrence.